# On mouse left button down showing dotted outline on tabs in IE

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting a weird issue in IE. I am using bootstrap tabs on my webpage.

**ISSUE:**
When I left click and hold it on the tab, it is showing dotted outline around the tab. This is not happening in Chrome but only in IE. BTW I am using IE11. Please see below screenshot which I took on IE11 while holding mouse left click down on the tab.

[image]

As soon as I release mouse button, that outline goes, because I have given following CSS code for it:

```
.nav-tabs > .active > a, .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > .active > a:focus {
        outline:none;
 }
```

Can someone tell me how to get rid of outline when user press left mouse button on the tab? I understand typically when user clicks on it, it will show dotted outline for fraction of second and then it goes off. But coming and going of that doesn't look good to me, I want to get rid of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with this css, it may help you.    .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {    outline: 0px !important; }

Answer (score 0):

Put `css` like

```
a:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: And use meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` for ie 9. i think it will resolve.

Comment: Can you tell me version of IE??

Comment: `a:focus {
outline: 0;
} ` like this you putted css rite??

Comment: Yes, Raghavendra. I am using IE11

Comment: put this meta tag and check once `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`

Answer (score 0):

Add `:active` pseudoclass

```
.nav-tabs > .active > a, 
.nav-tabs > .active > a:hover, 
.nav-tabs > .active > a:focus, 
.nav-tabs > .active > a:active {
  outline:none;
}
```